# How to iterate through a python array and compare the element to the previous element?

Tags: python, arrays, loops

I'm having a bit of trouble with an array in python. I want to loop through it, and compare element n to element n-1. For example:

```
 [(11, 11), (11, 10), (11, 9), (11, 8), (11, 7), (11, 6), (11, 5),
  (11, 4), (10, 4), (9, 4), (8, 4), (8, 5), (7, 5), (6, 5), (5, 5),
  (4, 5), (3, 5), (3, 4), (3, 3), (2, 3), (1, 3), (1, 2), (1, 1), (1, 0)]
```

Using the above array, I want to apply the following moves/logic:

- 0,1 = right
- 1,0 = down
- -1,0 = up
- 0,-1 = left

So if the element of the array we are looking at's first value is less than the previous I want to print up.

So the result for the array above would be (assuming the start is always 0,0)

```
[Start, down, right, right, right, down, down, right, right, down, 
down, down, down, down, left, down, down, down, right, right, right, 
right, right, right, right]
```

It's a tricky one to explain so apologies if this is a bit confusing. Also the element will never go diagonal so it will never got from (1,1) to (2,2) one one of the 2 sub-elements will change at any given time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considering that your array of coordinates is called `coords`, you could do:

```
steps = [(x2-x1, y2-y1) for ((x1, y1), (x2, y2)) in  zip(coords, coords[1:])]
```

Explanation:

- coords[1:] represents all coordinate pairs starting with the second one
- zip(coords, coords[1:]) makes pairs of each coordinate with the one before
- for an array of `n` corrdinate pairs, `zip` will output `n-1` steps, since `zip`'s output length is equal to the length of the shorter one of its arguments. So, due to the second list being shorter, the first list will only be enumerated excluding its last element (thanks [Ev. Kounis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6162307/ev-kounis) for suggesting this clarification)

EDIT: to make a list of strings representing the steps made, you can make a dictionary of possible movements:

```
coords = [(11, 11), (11, 10), (11, 9), (11, 8), (11, 7), (11, 6),
          (11, 5), (11, 4), (10, 4), (9, 4), (8, 4), (8, 5), (7, 5),
          (6, 5), (5, 5), (4, 5), (3, 5), (3, 4), (3, 3), (2, 3),
          (1, 3), (1, 2), (1, 1), (1, 0)]

movements = {
        (0, 1):  'right',
        (1, 0):  'down',
        (-1, 0): 'up',
        (0, -1): 'left'
        }

steps = [movements[(x2-x1, y2-y1)]
         for ((x1, y1), (x2, y2)) in zip(coords, coords[1:])]
```

Comment: I would also mention that the first `coords` in `zip` actually goes up to `-1` index position (`coords[:-1]`) since `zip` returns an iterator whose length is the length of its smallest argument. +1

Comment: Thankyou, the logic here is exactly what I need. I will mark this as the answer. Take care

Answer (score 1):

You could always just access index `i-1` for the previous element starting at `i=1`:

```
from operator import sub

lst = [(11, 11), (11, 10), (11, 9), (11, 8), (11, 7), (11, 6), (11, 5), (11, 4), (10, 4), (9, 4), (8, 4), (8, 5), (7, 5), (6, 5), (5, 5), (4, 5), (3, 5), (3, 4), (3, 3), (2, 3), (1, 3), (1, 2), (1, 1), (1, 0)]

d = {(0, 1):'right', (1, 0): 'down', (-1, 0): 'up', (0, -1): 'left'}

result = [d[tuple(map(sub, lst[i], lst[i-1]))] for i in range(1, len(lst))]

print(result)
# ['left', 'left', 'left', 'left', 'left', 'left', 'left', 'up', 'up', 'up', 'right', 'up', 'up', 'up', 'up', 'up', 'left', 'left', 'up', 'up', 'left', 'left', 'left']
```